# JSCH (SFTP) fails on change dir on sub folders level (second level)

Tags: sftp, jsch

JSch's SFTP channel fails to change directory when the previous directory is not in the root directory (ftp home). It happens only on some SFTP servers and not all of them.

For example the directory structure is this:

- /

  - level-1

    - level-2

`cd level-1` (OK)
`cd level-2` (fails)

It throws an exception like this

```
4: Folder not found: /level-1/level-2
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2569)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._realpath(ChannelSftp.java:2100)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:315)
```

The SFTP server with error returns `/` as *realpath* for the root. The other server that didn't fail returns full path list `/usr/account`.

Comment: Shouldn't the title read "(second level)"?

Comment: good eyes!! corrected the title (send level -> second level). it was a typo. thanks.

Comment: FWIW if you're getting this when connecting to a Apache SSHD-based (`org.apache.sshd`) Java SFTP server, check whether you have set `SshServer.setFileSystemFactory()` correctly; in my case I had set it up using `.` as the home dir - which, even when converted to an absolute path (`Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath()`) contained a trailing dot; `<absolute path>/./` segment; causing issues on the client end. Fixing the path (`Paths.get("")...` - just `""` instead of `"."`) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found source code for JSCH 0.1.49 and traced it. I found out there is a method named _realPath that throws exception when server fails to return the realpath.
The input parameter for the method is **absolute path of remote folder** so I commented the exception out and instead returned the absolute path. Everything works fine.

This is the modified code. Note the original code works most of the time and the change I made is for rare situation that the server fails to return realpath on second level directory (sub folders), and there is no guarantee that it works for all servers.

```
//com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp
private byte[] _realpath(String path) throws ... {
...
if (type == SSH_FXP_STATUS) {
  i = buf.getInt();
  /* Some servers fail to return the realPath
   on second level of directory (subfolders).
   original code is commented out and replaced with a return.*/
  //throwStatusError(buf, i);
  return (path.getBytes());
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I looks like a server-side problem/bug to me. The server might implement the `SSH_FXP_REALPATH` request incorrectly.

Is the account, you log in with, chrooted? Who does the chrooting, the SFTP server or is it system-level chrooting?

If you share log file, you may get more specific answer.

You might also try some other SFTP client that follows SFTP specification and uses the `SSH_FXP_REALPATH` request, when entering directory (many clients do not). It does not have to be Java library. Any client, even GUI, would do. Just for testing, if it gets into the same troubles. [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) for instance uses the `SSH_FXP_REALPATH`. Just try to connect and enter the `/level-1/level-2`. *(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks Martyn, it was server side bug. Unfortunately, I had no access to server and I had to fix it in client. I found the solution.